# Artemis load balancing via queue federation plus HA replication policy

Tags: high-availability, activemq-artemis

I want to build an ActiveMQ Artemis system that can communicate with another cross-region server and perform load balancing and high availability at the same time.

Therefore, I have two virtual machines (172.16.212.32 & 172.16.212.33). Each virtual machine has two replication servers for high availabilit, and I've set up federation in each server to achieve load balancing.
I know that federation can set the ha option, but I think the replication server will perform a better failover effect locally.

There is the setting below.

Master (172.16.212.20) in VM (172.16.212.32) :

```xml
      <connectors>
         <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://172.16.212.20:61616</connector>
         <connector name="master-connector33">tcp://172.16.212.22:61616</connector>
         <connector name="slave-connector33">tcp://172.16.212.23:61616</connector>
      </connectors>

      <broadcast-groups>
         <broadcast-group name="bg-group32">
            <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
         </broadcast-group>
      </broadcast-groups>

      <discovery-groups>
         <discovery-group name="dg-group32">
            <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
         </discovery-group>
      </discovery-groups>

      <cluster-user>root</cluster-user>
      <cluster-password>syscom#1</cluster-password>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="cluster32">
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group32"/>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
      
      <ha-policy>
         <replication>
            <master>
                <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
            </master>
         </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <federations>
         <federation name="master-federation32">
            <upstream name="master-upstream33">
               <circuit-breaker-timeout>1000</circuit-breaker-timeout>
               <static-connectors>
                  <connector-ref>master-connector33</connector-ref>
               </static-connectors>
               <policy ref="policySetA"/>
            </upstream>
            <upstream name="slave-upstream33">
               <circuit-breaker-timeout>1000</circuit-breaker-timeout>
               <static-connectors>
                  <connector-ref>slave-connector33</connector-ref>
               </static-connectors>
               <policy ref="policySetA"/>
            </upstream>

            <policy-set name="policySetA">
               <policy ref="queue-federation" />
            </policy-set>
             <queue-policy name="queue-federation" >
               <include queue-match="#" address-match="#" />
            </queue-policy>
         </federation>
      </federations>
```

Slave (172.16.212.21) in VM (172.16.212.32):

```xml
      <connectors>
         <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://172.16.212.21:61616</connector>
         <connector name="master-connector33">tcp://172.16.212.22:61616</connector>
         <connector name="slave-connector33">tcp://172.16.212.23:61616</connector>
      </connectors>

      <broadcast-groups>
         <broadcast-group name="bg-group32">
            <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
         </broadcast-group>
      </broadcast-groups>

      <discovery-groups>
         <discovery-group name="dg-group32">
            <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
         </discovery-group>
      </discovery-groups>

      <cluster-user>root</cluster-user>
      <cluster-password>syscom#1</cluster-password>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="cluster32">
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group32"/>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
      
      <ha-policy>
         <replication>
            <slave>
                <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
            </slave>
         </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <federations>
         <federation name="slave-federation32">
            <upstream name="master-upstream33" priority-adjustment="0">
               <circuit-breaker-timeout>1000</circuit-breaker-timeout>
               <static-connectors>
                  <connector-ref>master-connector33</connector-ref>
               </static-connectors>
               <policy ref="policySetA"/>
            </upstream>
            <upstream name="slave-upstream33" priority-adjustment="0">
               <circuit-breaker-timeout>1000</circuit-breaker-timeout>
               <static-connectors>
                  <connector-ref>slave-connector33</connector-ref>
               </static-connectors>
               <policy ref="policySetA"/>
            </upstream>

            <policy-set name="policySetA">
               <policy ref="queue-federation" />
            </policy-set>
             <queue-policy name="queue-federation" >
               <include queue-match="#" address-match="#" />
            </queue-policy>
         </federation>
      </federations>
```

172.16.212.22 and 172.16.212.23 are master and slave servers in VM 172.16.212.33.

After set up like that the master server in different VM can communicate with each other, and slave servers announce backup successfully. But the load balancing does not work.

Does the idea of federation plus ha replication policy not work?
I would appreciate it if you have any advice for me.

Comment: If you want HA + load-balancing why not simply using a cluster? Federation is really meant for brokers (or sets of brokers) that serve unique applications but still need some level of integration between each other for sharing messages here and there. What you've configured is federation for *every* address which seems more like you'd simply want to use clustering. Eliminating federation and just clustering would simplify your configuration substantially.

Comment: Although it is not clear in this case, the system will be used in the Kubernetes containers, I may have producers on one network segment and consumers on another network segment. I think that the cluster server discovered that it uses UDP multicast, so it cannot move messages across the WAN between regions. On the other hand, a cluster with more than two servers will not failback, and ha replication will not be able to achieve load balancing.

Comment: If you're using Kubernetes (or any cloud environment where UDP multicast doesn't work) and you want to configure an ActiveMQ Artemis cluster then you can use our [JGroups integration](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html#server-discovery) with [JGroup's KUBE_PING](https://github.com/jgroups-extras/jgroups-kubernetes) discovery protocol. Once the brokers are discovered then normal core bridges (using TCP) are formed between the nodes. These bridges allow messages and other cluster meta-data for flow between nodes for things like load-balancing.

Comment: To be clear, a cluster can be formed of HA pairs. In this way you get the benefits of both load-balancing *and* fail-over.

Comment: So in the Kubernetes environment, do you recommend using JGroup instead of the federation? What could happen to the current federation+ha architecture?